# Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics' and Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics'

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I try to generate angular material data-table, I am getting below error. Please guide me to resolve this error.

ng command used for generate the data-table:

```
ng g @angular/material:material-table --name=data-table
```

after executing above ng command I am getting below error in my terminal

Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics'

```
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\my-wks\meanStackDemo\node_modules\@angular\material\schematics\ng-generate\table\index.js:10:22)
```

Please share your suggestion or guidance to resolve this. Thanks .

Happy Holidays!:-)

Answer (score 22):

When I tried installing angular material to my project I got the same error like

> Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks' in angular 7

So I  did

```
npm i @angular-devkit/schematics
npm i @angular-devkit/core
```

it resolves the problem.

Comment: Fixed my error updating from 8 to 9.0, also see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16392

Comment: After your commands, I did ```npm audit fix``` and ```ionic build``` and then I was also able to add compoents and pages.

Answer (score 8):

Finally I got blow conclusion from this error.

## 1 make sure below command is executed in right directory or not.

'`npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations hammerjs`'

for my case
'C:\Users\Lenovo\my-wks\meanStackDemo\contacts>' -- correct path

'C:\Users\Lenovo\my-wks\meanStackDemo>'--previous wrong path

now i can generate the data-table component by using below command
'`ng g @angular/material:material-table --name=data-table`'

Thanks rvkant! your explanation is very useful to understand the issue.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

As per material design documentation

> Blockquote Schematics are included with both @angular/cdk and @angular/material. Once you install the npm packages, they will be available through the Angular CLI.

Using the command below will install Angular Material, the Component Dev Kit (CDK), and Angular Animations in your project. Then it will run the install schematic.

`ng add @angular/material`

And then generate data-table component by using the following command

`ng generate @angular/material:table <component-name>`

Comment: Hi rvkant, thanks for response. but I am not able to execute above command. am getting 'C:\Users\Lenovo\my-wks\meanStackDemo\contacts>ng add @angular/material
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
Error: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics/tasks'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)'

Comment: yes! now i got it. "npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations hammerjs" this command executed in wrong path. thats why its not installing.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@angular/material` command is not installing all the dependencies currently, that is why it throws an error.

Try to run

```sh
npm i @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations
```

Now again install angular material.