# Why does Angular CLI 9.01 fails to create a bazel project?

Tags: angular, bazel

**Steps to Reproduce**

- remove Angular's global installation: `npm uninstall -g angular-cli && npm cache clean --force`
- install Angular 9, globally: `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
- intall bazel globally: `npm i -g @angular/bazel`
- start an Angular 9 project using bazel: 
  `$ ng new bazel-project --defaults --collection=@angular/bazel`

**Observed Behavior**
Angular CLI fails to create the project: `An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/schematics'`

**Expected Behavior**
The project is created

**Additional Material**

`ng --version` yields the following:

```
$ ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.0.1
Node: 13.8.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.1
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.1
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.1
@schematics/angular          9.0.1
@schematics/update           0.900.1
rxjs                         6.5.3
```

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940350/error-cannot-find-module-angular-devkit-schematics-and-cannot-find-module)

Comment: Note that the error I reported happens when creating a new project, whereas the links you referred me to address existing projects. Also, notice that the "missing" schematic package was installed!

Answer (score 0):

I erease Node and Angular from my machine, and re-installed them from scratch. The, I followed [these instructions](https://angular.io/guide/bazel) to create a new ng project.

The option to use Bazel in a new application, by installing @angular/bazel globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/bazel
ng new my-project --collection=@angular/bazel
```

Does not work, as per my steps above.

The option to opt-in an existing application:

```
ng new my-project --collection=@angular/bazel
npm install -g @angular/bazel
```

works, without creating the WORKSPACE and BUILD files, which I expected would be created.

I'm closing this issue and will wait until the Angular folks fix this.